# How to assign a column to be True or False boolean in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, boolean

My current code to assign a boolean value to my pyspark dataframe is:
`df = df.withColumn('my_column_name', True)`

However, I get the error: "AssertionError: col should be Column"

Do I need to have "True" value wrapped with col(BooleanType(True))? I don't think I should be casting it as a lit string

Comment: Pass `True` inside `lit()` -> `df.withColumn("my_column_name", lit(True)).show()` as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df = df.withColumn("my_column_name", F.lit(1).cast('boolean'))
```

Comment: Would this also work? ```from pyspark.sql import functions as F``` ```df = df.withColumn("my_column_name", F.lit("True").cast(BooleanType()))```

Comment: Using F.lit("True").cast(BooleanType()) would not assign a boolean value to the column. Instead, you can use lit(True).cast(BooleanType()) to create a literal boolean value and cast it to the BooleanType(). @deesolie

Comment: Thanks y'all, trying these out now! Appreciate the quick responses

Comment: I think all three ways work – it's a matter of taste. I personally like casting `1/0` to `True/False`, but `F.lit("True"), F.lit(True)`, and even `F.lit("T")` or `F.lit("t")` will all work when you cast to a `boolean` type